# What a community user can do on the custom object record?

Tags: community, custom-object, customer-community, record, npsp

Has anyone implemented a community from a NPSP org ?

I need to launch a community with a NPSP org, but I have a question that the documentation doesn't answer me.

What a user can do on a record of a custom object with each community licence ? (read only, create, edit, delete)

Is it different from a standard object ?

Comment: I am not up to speed with `Nonprofit Success Pack (NPSP)` but I'd imagine you can control the permissions in the usual way. Setup > Sites > select the site > Public Access Settings

Answer (score 1):

This is not clearly stated in the [help documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5), but you can assign community users full CRUD permissions to any custom object.  This includes custom objects in managed packages like NPSP.

Note that there can be unexpected limitations on custom object functionality despite having given full permissions to the community profile.  For example:  If you have a custom object MyObj that is in master-detail relationship with Contact, a Customer Community license user may not be able to create a MyObj record in certain situations even though you have granted CRUD permissions for MyObj.  This is due to underlying community share restrictions on the Contact record that cannot be bypassed.

If your project relies on custom objects that are in master-detail to Contact or Account, you should do detailed testing in a sandbox to ensure the system will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks David for your answer. When you said that a Customer Community license user may not be able to create a MyObj record in certain situations.

It concerns also customer community plus user and partner community or not ?

Comment: No, just Customer Community license.