# Giving community users access to records via junction object

Tags: security, sharing, sharing-sets

I have a junction object called `Junction__c`. It has Master-Detail to `PersonAccount` and another object called `Mortgage__c`.

I have a checkbox on `Junction__c` called `Access_Granted__c`. When this checkbox is true then the `Mortgage__c` object should be shared with the `PersonAccount`.

Is it possible to do this? I have tried with Apex sharing but soon realised that community users can't be added to share objects. I don't see a way that it's possible through sharing sets but I hope I am wrong.

We are using Partner licences so cannot utilise Apex sharing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What a community user can do on the custom object record?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260460/what-a-community-user-can-do-on-the-custom-object-record)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe the specific community license you have (Partner, Customer Plus, etc).  Sharing works differently for the different license types.